# суммирование переменной в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, вывожу данные из базы данных функцией    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
 в одной из колонок выводятся строки с числами    '.$row['itog'].'у.е
ето примерно от 5 до 30 строк чисел как правильно их посчитать и вывести сумму ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если также необходимы какие-то другие данные из строк в таблице, то перед циклом while создай переменную:

```
$summ = 0;
```

А в цикле увеличивай значение этой переменной:

```
$summ += $row['itog'];
```

Если же нужна только сумма конкретного столбца, то лучше сразу запросить её SQL запросом:

```
SELECT SUM(`column_name`) FROM `table_name` WHERE condition;
```